# Installation of Steam client and games

Tags: steam

If I install the Steam client onto my SSD, can I install games I download on Steam to my HDD?

Comment: Yes you just need to make a new library location on the drive.....

Answer (score 2):

When you install a game, you can chose where to install it as one of the steps. By default, this is set to `~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps` or `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Steam\SteamApps`. You can set a different location, creating a new library in that location (will create a folder called something like **SteamApps**). From there, you can either then select that Library to install, and you can drag manifest and Application Data from **common**.

[image]

In this Dropdown, there will also be something like **Create new library on drive x**

Comment: Kinda pointless to answer a question with 3 different duplicates all containing that answer.